# Analytical solution for $\min_{q_i,u_j} Q := \sum_{i,j} | A_{i,j} - B_{i,j} \, q_i \, u_j |^2$ given $A_{i,j}$ and $B_{i,j}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-decomposition

Is there an analytical solution for $q_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $u_j \in \mathbb{C}$ in $\min_{q_i,u_j} Q := \sum_{i,j} | A_{i,j} - B_{i,j} \, q_i \, u_j |^2$ given $A_{i,j} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $B_{i,j} \in \mathbb{C}$, where $i$ and $j$ denote finite (matrix) integer indices.

If so, how do you calculate it?